# Creating Chart using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml, charts

I need to create chart using javascript.
should be look like as in link below (click play to see chart sample):

Please suggest me which control should i use/purchase, which allows me to create chart in such style shown in link.
chart data will be in xml format and i am asp.net developer
thanks

Comment: Unless you need the user to be able to interact with them very much, you would probably be better off creating these charts in .NET (performance-wise, and browser compatibility-wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For charting in HTML5 pages is good to use javascript library. 
I recomand these charting.

this one is like your charting..
http://www.jqplot.com/tests/OHLCTests.php
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/compound_charts.html#candlestick_charts

**Others**
http://www.splashnology.com/blog/javascripts/290.html
http://www.highcharts.com/
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/charts/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Google charts have a good api and are free.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for JS candlestick charts, [jQPlot has them](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/OHLCTests.php).

If you want to look at other options, here's a list of JS charts:
http://www.splashnology.com/blog/javascripts/290.html

Some of these are also interactive. If I remember correctly, StackOverflow uses Flot for the [reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396458?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top).

Answer (score 1):

Just have to sneak my favorite answer in here: [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) and it's charting plugin, [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The best option, in my opinion is Google Api Chart. Easy to learn and usefully as said Q_the_novice.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like YUI for charting (at least YUI2). I wrote a tutorial on using YUI to create charts, which you can see here:

http://www.devseo.co.uk/blog/view/using-the-yui-chart-component

It's fundamentally easy to do, the charts are drawn in flash and you can customise most of their look and feel. Read more:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/charts/